# Как составить программу с использованием оператора цикла?

Tags: c++, математика, visual-c++, ряды, численные-методы

Функция: sqrt(pow(a, 2) + b)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Область сходимости: (-1 < b/a^2 < 1)

Разложение в ряд: [image: разложение в ряд]

Короче у меня уже есть написанный код, но я уверен что он работает не правильно и не могу понять как делать дальше и реализовывать программу, помогите пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
double up(double temp) {
    double p = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= temp; i += 2) p *= i;
    return p;
}

double bottom(double temp) {
    double m = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= temp; i += 2) m *= i;
    return m;
}

double fraction(double temp, double a, double b) {
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= temp; i += 2) {
        result = b / pow(a, 2);
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    double temp = 0, form = 0, esp, a, b;

        cout << "Область сходимости: (-1 < b/a^2 < 1)" << endl << "a, b = ";
        cin >> a;
        cin >> b;
        cout << "Введите esp: ";
        cin >> esp;

        while (fabs(form) < esp) {
            form += a * abs( up(temp) / bottom(temp) * fraction(temp, a, b));
            temp += 2;
            cout << form << endl;
        }
        cout.precision(5);
        cout << "Приближенная (-1 < " << b << "/" << a << "^2 < 1)" << fixed << form << endl;
        cout << "Точное (-1 < " << b << "/" << a << "^2 < 1)" << sqrt(pow(a, 2) + b) << endl;

    return 0;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь, я не очень вас огорчу тем, что это разложение в ряд несколько иной функции? а именно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что сравнивать результаты надо с этой функцией...

Ну, а сам ряд можно считать примерно так:

```
double series(double a, double b, double eps = 1e-7)
{
    double x = b/(a*a*a);
    double t = x/3, s = 1 + x/3;
    for(int k = 2; abs(t) > eps/a; k+=3) s += t *= -x*k/(k+4);
    return s*a;
}
```

Вот, убедитесь: https://ideone.com/L1QMr9

Comment: Опять анонисный минусатор проснулся? Интересно, что ну никогда не говорит, что ему не нравится. Наверное, мой аватар :)

Comment: наверное потому что за других решаете математику(минус не  от меня)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Ну тут же именно математически некорректная задача оказалась — ряд, не соответствующий функции.